# Get data from certain days and times

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a list of all labels that were printed for shipment. Because of the way we work, we only print a label when we are ready to ship it, so this gives me a good opportunity to use this data to find out when we print most labels, and thusly, our productivity. I want to show on what days we print them, and by hour (at 300 min increments).

I'd also like to go one step further, as Mondays are by far our busiest days, to see what times on a day of the week we print labels.

The data I have is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IttsloqjLCMU1VURlLJ8eThIJ4q57DKZ-li76QKuVw/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see, I have already been able to deduce how may labels we ship using which services and using which carriers, which is great. The cream coloured tables are the tables I'd like to know how to populate. I have tried countif and I'm guessing because it's a timestamp I'm referencing it won't work?

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For days of week use

```
=COUNTIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT($C$3:$C$1333,"dddd")),"="&F21)
```

[image]

For times of day use

```
=COUNTIFS(ArrayFormula(N($C$3:$C$1333)-TRUNC($C$3:$C$1333)),">="&F28,
          ArrayFormula(N($C$3:$C$1333)-TRUNC($C$3:$C$1333)),"<="&F29)
```

[image]

Put 2 formulas together for combination of days of week and times of day

In column `C` you have data like

[image]